# Jquery .load removes <script>...</script> content

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, load

when i call .load function, it brings me the HTML code but it wipes out the `<script>` content, code from cards.tpl.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //anything
</script>
<div style="float:right" class="blah">
<!-- anything -->
</div>
```

code from index.php:

```
<div id="cards">
     <?php include 'tpl/cards.tpl.php'; ?>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#drawCard').click(function(){
            $('#cards').load("tpl/cards.tpl.php",function(){
            });
    });
</script>
```

When PHP includes the content, it includes the `<script>`, however when i click on #drawCard the JavaScript only brings me the div. I just saw that .load actually removes script tags but they are executed, do bound events remain after execution?

**Edit:**

Ok, finally i got a solution to the problem behind all this. Using load() to call `<script></script>` that contains event binding code will give you tons of headaches. DON'T DO IT!. If your real problem was dealing with issues of binding after using the $.load() function, then i recommend doing the following:

Replaced the all the click(), on('click') events  with a plugin called [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) using livequery('click'), it works 100%.

Not with in the mood of oppening a new question but why does JQuery tells you to replace live() with on() when it will not work as expected?.

**edit for JAAulde**

```
<div id="cards">
    <!-- this content is replaced -->
    <div value="t1" class="impar tecnologia unselected investigated notUsed">stuff</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of content replaced-->
</div>
```

and using this jQuery code:

```
$("#cards").on('click','.unselected',(function(e){}));
```

This works before load, and does not work after

Comment: I'm having a hard time making sense of your question.  Can you pare it down to only relevant code?  Also, what is the first code block?  Is that the contents of cards.tpl.php?

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense now.

Comment: Hey, I remember you now!  I tried helping you with another issue earlier in the week.  Is this a card game you're building?

Comment: I think it may be an issue with using on for dynamic events.  Let me look into it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery removes all scripts from content being inserted into the DOM and places them in the HEAD for execution (then, for some reason, removes them from the HEAD afterward). Rest assured that all scripts you shipped were inserted and executed.

To answer your edit, `.live()` was a clever use of event bubbling which delegates the handling of specified events on a collection up to the `document` object.

jQuery deprecated `.live()` when they introduced `.delegate()`[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) because the latter allows you to specify a container to which you should delegate, rather than always using `document`. This is preferred because it allows you to limit the impact of such delegated events (less bubbled events to deal with, shorter trip up the chain to the handler, less selector matching/filtering, etc).

`.delegate()` itself has now been superseded with `.on()`[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in a unification of the event API. If you pass a selector as the second param to `.on()` you are telling jQuery to delegate the event(s) named in param 1 to the element(s) matching the given selector.

Thus all calls to `.live()` should be replaced with a properly scoped call to `.on()`.

Comment: using the following $('#parentId').on('click','#insideDivId',function(){//somestuff}) will loose it binding when you use load to refresh the content of #insideDivId. How should a properly scoped call be?

Comment: In your code, you appear to be replacing the contents of the DIV with ID `cards`. Since it is this DIV's content being replaced, and not this DIV itself, it seems it would be best to delegate to it: `$('#cards').on('click', '.elementWhichCanBeReplacedDuringLoad', function (e) {});`

Comment: just saw what you did.. it would need me to remove all content from the div and add it again.. thanks would need to try, going to stay with livequery, way more simple.

Comment: @EH_warch, no it wouldn't require all content to be removed. Trust me, if live query is working, .on will work as well--with less loaded code and a more efficient handling.

Comment: It's not a matter of trust!, i'm sure it can work, however the code i edited last wont, so it might not be as simple as with livequery.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing $(document).ready(...) from your card.tpl include.

I looked back in your history, (after I asked you to clean it up :-p) to the original code you had posted up and I found this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#toggleMax').click(function(){
      // code
   });
   // more code
</script>
```

Then I coded something similar and it worked. The only thing I changed was wrapping your code in document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {  // Note the document.ready call here.
       $('#toggleMax').click(function(){
          // code
       });
       // more code
   });
</script>
```

Comment: but clicking does not do anything :(

Comment: I reproduced this on my box and found this out.  This is my new answer.

Comment: hehe, in fact it was not me how add the `<script>` tags it was one you that eddited, originaly i had ... javascriptcode ... I always use `$(function(){ ... });` for jquery code, it's like basic stuff >.<!, but yeah sorry for omiting it! Anyway, that works before load and not after load as i last stated.

Comment: So this didn't work for you?   You have document.ready in the cards.tpl.php file?  I'm going to run everything you gave me and see.